# Is magnetic moment a conserved quantity in Magnetostatics?

Tags: magnetic-fields, conservation-laws, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics

I am interested in the equations of **Magnetostatics**, but without the knowledge that electric currents create magnetic fields. In other words, expressing the equations *only in terms of the magnetic moment* of permanent magnets, no "Steady state" currents, or any other kind of current.

These are what I found. If something is wrong, please let me know

$$\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{B} = 0$$
$$\nabla \times\boldsymbol{B} = \nabla\times\boldsymbol{M} \mu_0$$
$$\boldsymbol{F_m} = \nabla (\boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{B})$$

Where $\boldsymbol{B}$ is the magnetic field, $\boldsymbol{M}$ is the magnetic moment density, $\boldsymbol{F_m}$ is the magnetostatic force on a magnetic moment $\boldsymbol{m}$, and $\mu_0$ is the vacuum permeability.

Now, since Electrostatics has analogues to those three equations, plus an equation of conservation of charge*, $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{J} = -\frac{d \rho}{dt}$, I'm wandering:
**Is there an analogous law of conservation in Magnetostatics? Is total magnetic moment conserved in Magnetostatics? How about in Electrostatics, or in general?**

*From https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html. But maybe I'm wrong in claiming it applies in electrostatics, like a commenter says. If so, I limit the question to "Is magnetic moment conserved in general?"

Comment: Does electrostatics have $\nabla\cdot J = -\partial_t\rho$? Surely in electrostatics both sides of this are zero by definition.

Comment: @jacob1729 Yes, that makes sense... I read it from https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html, which uses it when explaining magnetostatics with electric currents. But maybe I'm wrong in thinking it how I do in my question... I edited it

Comment: Your second equation cannot be right, the curl of a vector gives you a vector but the divergence of a vector is a scalar.

Comment: Also the equation cannot be as simple as the continuity equation for the electric charge as the magnetic moment density is a vector not a scalar.

Comment: @Mauricio Yes, I typed dot instead of cross, edited now. I took it from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization#Magnetostatics, which states Curl(H) = 0, and since the definition of H is = 1/mu.B - M (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field#H-field_and_magnetic_materials), then that equation follows, I think...

Comment: There is something weird with that page, that does not agree with curl(H) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics . Oh I guess it is because the first definition assumes $\mathbf J=0$

Comment: @Mauricio It agrees here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics#Magnetization, by considering J to be zero, I think. But if you know of a better source for these equations I'm open, I had a hard time finding it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write Maxwell's equations
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf E =\rho/\epsilon_0 \tag1$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf B =0 \tag2$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E =-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf B\tag3$$
$$\nabla \times  \mathbf B =\mu_0 \mathbf J+ \epsilon_0\mu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf E \tag4$$

Take the divergence of (4) and use (1) to get the continuity equation for the charge
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf J = - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho  \tag5$$
The continuity equation has nothing to do with statics, it holds always.

In the case of electrostatics as $\partial E/\partial t =0$, the continuity equation becomes $\partial \rho/\partial t =0$. Which in turns means $\nabla \cdot \mathbf J=0$.

Now let us replace $\mathbf B=\mu_0(\mathbf H+\mathbf M)$, we get
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf E =\rho/\epsilon_0 \tag1$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf H =-\nabla \cdot \mathbf M \tag6$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E =-\mu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf M-\mu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf H \tag7$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf H = \mathbf J-\nabla \times \mathbf M+ \epsilon_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf E \tag8$$
these new magnetic equations look more symmetric between $E$ and $H$, specially if we define $\rho_m=\nabla \cdot \mathbf M$ and $\mathbf J_m=\nabla \times \mathbf M$. We get
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf E =\rho/\epsilon_0 \tag1$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf H =-\rho_m \tag9$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E =-\mu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf M-\mu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf H \tag7$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf H = \mathbf J-\mathbf J_m+ \epsilon_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf E \tag{10}$$

Note that by construction $\nabla \cdot \mathbf J_m = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf M )=0$ (divergence of a curl is always 0). Which looks a lot like the electrostatic conditions, the only problem is that $\rho_m $ is not related to $\mathbf J_m$ so you cannot say anything about it. In general $\partial \rho_m / \partial t \neq 0$ even in magnetostatics.

Edit: earlier I made an argument that if you replace $\mathbf K=\mathbf \partial M/\partial t$ in equation (7), you can do a similar trick as we can do with (4), and get $\nabla \cdot \mathbf K = -\partial \rho_m /\partial t$, but if you unpack it, it is just a trivial equation.